# How to predict a new text with doc2vec and LogisticRegression

Tags: nlp, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis, doc2vec

i'm new to python and trying to predict a new text by using Doc2vec and logisticRegression

For example "i am happy" return POS , "i am sad" return NEG

Below is my example code download from https://github.com/nisarg64/Sentiment-Analysis-Word2Vec/blob/master/doc2vec_sentiment.py

```
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
import numpy
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

model = Doc2Vec.load('./imdb.d2v')

train_arrays = numpy.zeros((25000, 128))
train_labels = numpy.zeros(25000)

for i in range(12500):
    prefix_train_pos = 'TRAIN_POS_' + str(i)
    prefix_train_neg = 'TRAIN_NEG_' + str(i)
    train_arrays[i] = model.docvecs[prefix_train_pos]
    train_arrays[12500 + i] = model.docvecs[prefix_train_neg]
    train_labels[i] = 1
    train_labels[12500 + i] = 0


test_arrays = numpy.zeros((25000, 128))
test_labels = numpy.zeros(25000)

for i in range(12500):
    prefix_test_pos = 'TEST_POS_' + str(i)
    prefix_test_neg = 'TEST_NEG_' + str(i)
    test_arrays[i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_pos]
    test_arrays[12500 + i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_neg]
    test_labels[i] = 1
    test_labels[12500 + i] = 0

# for i in range(50000):
#     prefix_unsup = 'TEST_POS_' + str(i)
#     test_arrays[i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_pos]
#     test_arrays[12500 + i] = model.docvecs[prefix_test_neg]
#     test_labels[i] = 1
#     test_labels[12500 + i] = 0


classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(train_arrays, train_labels)

LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001)


#unsup = classifier.predict(s)

score = classifier.score(test_arrays, test_labels)
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize



print(score)
#here is where i want to predict the text
classifier.predict("input text here")
```

i had tried this before

```
v1= model.infer_vector(["I","love","chatbot"])
classifier.predict(v1)
```

but this is the error code

```
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\doc2vec.py", line 543, in infer_vector
    doctag_vectors, doctag_locks = self.trainables.get_doctag_trainables(doc_words, self.docvecs.vector_size)

AttributeError: 'DocvecsArray' object has no attribute 'vector_size'
```

Comment: Make sure you're using a recent version of `gensim` - the `DocvecsArray` class is only present in older versions, and any code which attempts to access a `vector_size` property must be relying on more recent `gensim` code.

Comment: the version i use is  gensim==3.4.0 however when I use the recent version of gensim another problem was "AttributeError: module 'gensim.utils' has no attribute 'smart_open' but anyway thanks for your help and i will try to using the recent version to running this file only